# git status gives me an error: bad index file sha1 signature

Tags: git, indexing, git-submodules

In my git repository I did an utf-8 conversion of many files, but only below the .git directory, so the .git directory was not touched.
Before this conversion I created a new testing branch, but now I cannot use my repo anymore, I cannot switch back to the master.
When I do:

```
git status
```

or any other git command I get:

```
error: bad index file sha1 signature 
fatal: index file corrupt 
fatal: 'git status --porcelain' failed in submodule core/kimai-mobile
```

I searched about it and found the command:

```
rm -f .git/index
```

and after this:

```
git reset
```

but this didn't help. I don't understand what is wrong.
Then I deleted the "submodule" core/kimai-mobile and suddenly I could use it again!

I had this other git repository in this directory in which I destroyed the other index file with my conversion. 
My problem was, that I thought that the "main" repositorys index file was meant.

Now it is working again :)

---

My question is, why did git look into this submodule although I had the whole folder of this submodule in my ignorelist?

This is the ignore file of my "main" git:

```
.gitignore

...
# kimai mobile
kimai-mobile
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Submodules are complete git repositories. So they can contain .git subdirectory (or at least a link to it).

So if you use your tool on all files besides .git in the root of the root repository you can still corrupt some internal .git files in submodules.